# General Way Of Comparing Results From Different Functions Over The Same Input

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The background is that I have a number of methods of doing lookups or perhaps estimations and I want to be able to compare
the results I get back from each.

This may be to pick the one with the best confidence level or to pick a majority
from the set.

Firstly if there is already something out there which might serve that would be good to know before I get too much deeper.

(My google search has not come up with anything useful)

I have the following method which seems to serve as a starting point but am not sure if it is the right way to go so would appreciate
comment and criticism.

(I know the example doesn't really fit with the use cases above but they are for simplest possible illustration)

```
trait TagFunction[A,B] {
  def tag: String
  def fn: A => B
  def apply(v: A) = (tag, fn(v))
}  

object Spong extends TagFunction[String,Option[String]] {
  val tag = "spong"
  val fn = (s: String) => if (s.length > 0 ) Some(s.toUpperCase) else None 
}

object Glarg extends TagFunction[String,Option[String]] {
  val tag = "glarg"
  val fn = (s: String) => if (s.length > 2 ) Some(s.reverse) else None 
}

val sf = Seq(Spong, Glarg)

sf.map(f => f("Trog"))

sf.map(f => f("a"))
```

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to do? Maybe this could be implemented as a fold on `sf`, but it isn't really clear what you are asking.

Comment: for some input x run list of functions f1(x) .. fn(x) which all return the same type of value but by differing methods 
and examine the outputs for each identified by the function that generated it called e.g. (f1,r1) .. (fn,rn).
I want to keep track of the relative quality of result from each function against input to a) see if combinations give better estimates
b) see which functions are more or less successful for given inputs. Difficult to give succinct explanation but hth.

Comment: Please give us examples of what the functions that evaluate the quality of a solution and combine estimates would look like.